# lightgbm ranker: predictions are all 0

Tags: python, machine-learning, lightgbm

I find some strange behaviour in the LGBMRanker, in the below example my label is a rank from 0 to 19 and one of the features is the label. The prediction function returns all 0, why? I would expect near perfect fit.

```
import numpy as np
from lightgbm import LGBMRanker

N = 20
y = np.arange(N)
X = np.random.normal(size=(N, 2))
X[:, 1] = y[0:]

model = LGBMRanker()
model.fit(X, y, group=[N])
print(model.predict(X))
```

Result:

```
[0, 0,..., 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this is it's related to `min_child_samples` - lightGBM won't split a node with fewer than 20 samples in it [by default](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMRanker.html#lightgbm.LGBMRanker.fit). You only have 20 samples total. Changing `min_child_samples = 1` should fix this:

```
model = LGBMRanker(min_child_samples=1)
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58708090/lightgbm-warning-there-are-no-meaningful-features-as-all-feature-values-are-co) as well.

If you have further issues, set `model.silent = False` to get lightGBM to print log statements while it trains to get more info on the process.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @frank-fineis looks right.  I just wanted to follow-up with the input and output for anyone else that was curious.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from lightgbm import LGBMRanker

N = 20
y = np.arange(N)
X = np.random.normal(size=(N, 2))
X[:, 1] = y[0:]
X = pd.DataFrame(X)

model = LGBMRanker(min_child_samples=1)
model.silent = False
model.fit(X, y, group=[N])
X["predicted_relevance"] = model.predict(X)

X = X.sort_values("predicted_relevance", ascending=False)
print(X)
```

Result:

```
[LightGBM] [Warning] Auto-choosing col-wise multi-threading, the overhead of testing was 0.000025 seconds.
You can set `force_col_wise=true` to remove the overhead.
[LightGBM] [Info] Total Bins 16
[LightGBM] [Info] Number of data points in the train set: 20, number of used features: 2
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
           0     1  predicted_relevance
19  0.288816  19.0             8.608105
18  1.301546  18.0             4.451251
17 -0.627074  17.0             1.345353
16 -0.334434  16.0            -0.612994
15  0.928000  15.0            -2.480486
14  1.384796  14.0            -3.497013
13 -0.045182  13.0            -4.483022
12  1.687175  12.0            -5.804756
11  0.231203  11.0            -6.470143
10  1.106199  10.0            -6.709271
9  -0.726748   9.0            -7.855950
8  -0.470821   8.0            -8.067369
7   0.189661   7.0            -8.165013
6   0.364313   6.0            -8.349157
3   0.363853   3.0            -8.527673
0   1.189089   0.0            -8.638177
5  -0.068059   5.0            -8.646692
4  -0.704554   4.0            -8.669182
2  -0.592100   2.0            -8.774775
1  -1.288528   1.0            -8.784167
```

Looks like LightGBM gets 19-6 in the right order but mixes up some of the least relevant results towards the end.  I believe the default gain is exponential. With 20 items and the default gain settings I believe LightGBM is spending about a millionth the effort in getting your item 1 and item 2 in the right order as it is spending in getting item 18 and item 19 in order.